# jQuery iframe modal close on form submit works partially

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I have a jQuery Modal dialog with an iframe in it, the iframe includes a form. When a user submits the form, I would like to close down the modal dialog.

**I managed to do that by adding the last bit of code written in this question, but the problem is that it closes the dialog only once, if I open it again and attempt to close it, it doesn't work.**

jquery modal script on index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showRegDialog(url) {
    $(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var horizontalPadding = 30;
            var verticalPadding = 30;
            $('<iframe id="externalSite" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="externalSite" src="' + url + '" />').dialog({
                title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'Choose your location',
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 700,
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                autoResize: true,
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    background: "black"
                }

            }).width(700 - horizontalPadding).height(700 - verticalPadding);            

    });
}
</script>
```

link on index.php to call showRegDialog modal:

```
<a href="javascript:showRegDialog('/register.php');">Register now</a>
```

This is the content of the register.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="parent.closeModal();">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added this to index.php:

```
function closeModal() {
    $("#externalSite").dialog("close");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try for your index.php

```
function closeModal() {
    $("#externalSite").dialog("destroy");
}
```